# HTTP/2 proxy for puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium, http2

I'm trying to run puppeteer with `--proxy-server` going to local http/2 proxy. All requests are failed as aborted.

```js
        this.server = http2.createServer();
        this.server.on('session', session=>{
            console.log('session', session);
        });
        this.server.on('stream', (stream, headers)=>{
            console.log(headers);
            stream.respond({':status': 200});
            stream.end('test');
        });
```

Session has been created, but then I see the error -903 (NGHTTP2_ERR_BAD_CLIENT_MAGIC).

```
Http2Session server (393) session created
Http2Session server (393) i/o stream consumed
Http2Session server (393) scheduling write
Http2Session server (393) refreshing state
Http2Session server (393) settings refreshed for session
Http2Session server (393) settings refreshed for session
Http2Session server (393) sending pending data
Http2Session server (393) nghttp2 has 9 bytes to send
Http2Session server (393) wants read? 1
Http2Session server (393) receiving 507 bytes
Http2Session server (393) receiving 507 bytes [wants data? 1]
Http2Session server (393) fatal error receiving data: -903
Http2Session server (393) destroying session
Http2Session server (393) closing session
Http2Session server (393) terminating session with code 2
Http2Session server (393) sending pending data
Http2Session server (393) nghttp2 has 17 bytes to send
Http2Session server (393) wants read? 0
```

If I use `http` it works fine.

```js
        this.server = http.createServer((req, res)=>
            this._proxy_http(req, res));
        this.server.on('connect', (req, socket, head)=>
            this._proxy_https(req, socket, head));
```

How to solve it with http/2?